# MIPS program doesn't stop

Tags: mips

I am new to MIPS, I have a simple code, in my main, which I call function "f". But somehow this program will run forever, can anyone help explain why that happening? Thanks!

```
f:
        li      $2, 0x2
        addi    $2, $2, 0x0
        jr      $ra
main:
        jal f
        .data
        .align 0
```

Comment: That program crashes on both MARS and QtSpim in their default configuration — and crashing is stopping!  Try running it in the debugger with single stepping to see where it doesn't do what you expect.  You might also mention what MIPS environment you're using, if you want to pursue.  Also, you can study many of the small, working sample programs here or otherwise on the web.

Comment: @ErikEidt, I am using spim to run it on my mac. On my mac, it will print 1 infinitely in my terminal

Comment: Why would it print 1 at all — there's no code in there that prints!?  Anyway, what do you see when you single step in the debugger?

Comment: @ErikEidt If I add "addi    $30, $31, 0x0" before the "jal f" and "addi    $31, $30, 0x0" after the "jal f". It will work properly, why??? I am so confused.....

Comment: Try using the debugger's single step feature and observe the effect of each instruction, assuming they have good input to work with (and if not then you've already gone too far).  Since this is so little code, it should be easy.  There's not even any memory references to debug, so all you have to do is observe the effect of each instruction on the registers.  As I have previously stated, it is not reproducible with either MARS or QtSpim on my system, so I can't explain what's happening.  In any case you can also start over with a sample program that is known to work and edit it as needed.

Comment: Is that the entire source file? Where is the `.text` directive to mark the beginning of the text (i.e. code) section? Where is the `.globl main` directive to export the `main` label?

Comment: `jal f` will overwrite the value of `$ra`, which is required to return from `main`. Therefore, you have to save that before calling other functions.

Comment: @MikeCAT, looks like you are right, so, for every function call in MIPS, I need to save $ra before jal?

Comment: @RBB No, you don't need to save `$ra` when you don't need that. (for example, when performing an infinite loop and won't "return from function")